# Поддержка CSS на iOS

Tags: css3, вёрстка, кроссплатформенность

Можно ли где-нибудь смотреть поддержку css свойств конкретно для iphone5, iphone6, ipad опр. версии и др. ?

На [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) не вижу такой возможности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или где узнать какая версия ios safari на iphone 5, а какая на iphone6 и т.д ?

Почему-то на iphone5 стандартная разметка `display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap;` разлазится. Ну и некоторые другие свойства не работают, хотелось бы узнать в подробностях.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На русском это означает: Safari привязан к операционной системе, поэтому значения в этом столбце означают версию iOS.

На iPhone5 может стоять как 9.3, так и 10.3. Всё зависит от того, обновляется ли операционная система на конкретном устройстве.

Comment: А самая ранняя версия 9.3 или может быть еще 9.1 ? Ищу не могу найти об этом какой-то типа такой же таблички с версиями

Comment: Нажмите вверху "Settings" и установите "Min. browser usage: 0.01%" - появятся более старые версии iOS

Comment: я имею ввиду какая самая ранняя версия может быть на iphone5, если флекс расползается, то может быть меньше чем 9.3 версия стоит

Comment: Дальше уже Google вам поможет, например вот https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices#Supported_iOS_releases

Answer (score 1):

Если вы нажмете кнопку `show all`, увидите следующую картину:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По умолчанию показываются самые новые версии, iPhone 5, скорее всего имеет cистему гораздо старее и вам нужно использовать префикс для его поддержки

Comment: да, наверное какая-то еще старенькая версия стоит  у заказчика

Comment: использую со всеми префиксами, но что-то всеравно не так как положено работает

Comment: Тогда я вам рекомендую https://www.browserstack.com/ для тестирования сайта на конкретной системе

Comment: хороший, но дорогой ресурс )

Comment: Да, однако 30 минут бесплатно

Comment: @user3178479 обычно в этом заинтересован работодатель, для него это копейки, а качество вёрстки важнее

Comment: разные есть заказчики